# Pending transaction DDEX

Tags: pending-transactions

I tried to initiate a sell order for EOSDAC on DDEX - however, i got stuck at the first hurdle in that the transaction from my address to DDEX has been pending for some time. I have enough gas for the transaction.

Here is the reference - 0x2f9d532cb164783c880668275e9c63a7b665037af06fa833fc6d730f57e43b0e

Would really appreciate it if someone could assist! let me know if you need more details. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction is still pending and the estimation confirmation time until it's mined is 13 hours.

[image]

**Why is it so long ?**

The network is currently congested (many pending transactions) and the miners choose which transactions to add in the next blocks. The rule is simple, they will proceed the transactions with the highest gasPrice in priority, meaning higher reward.

You set your gasPrice to 10Gwei which is too low compared to other transactions.

There is a great website called [Eth Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info) where you can basically see in real time what are the recommendations in terms of gasPrice to have his transaction confirmed quickly.

At the moment the recommendations are:
[image]

You can also approximate the time using the [Transaction Calculator](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php), your transaction will execute 80 000 units of gas at a price of 10Gwei.
They estimate to 28 817 seconds (8 hours)

[image]

**What can you do ?**

You can resubmit the exact same transaction (same nonce) with more gas (16Gwei should take less than 2 minutes to be mined).

If you resubmit the same transaction, presumably the transaction with the highest gasPrice will be mined and the other one will go on error because another transaction with the same nonce (transaction index for your account) would have been executed.

**MyEtherWallet:**

You can specify the gasPrice in the top right corner
[image]

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. Very informative. How do i change the gasPrice? Is this through MEW? Could i then initiate the trade on DDEX again despite the other transaction still pending (i.e. will this overwrite / cancel this existing transaction)? Or are you saying there is a way of resubmitting this exact same transaction reference - if the latter, how do i do this? Sorry for all the questions. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Just edited my answer with more details at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. So I changed my gasprice to 20gwei and then initiated the sell order again on DDEX. However, the transaction is not showing up. Could it be that the first transaction I initiated has blocked any new transactions being initiated for EosDac?

My public address is - 0x9d826907E4954847399fe577113e93EB5F8B0630

The only transaction I can see is the one pending from above. Do i have to just wait it out?

Comment: it should show up. Do you have the transaction hash?

Comment: All I can see when i put my public address into etherscan is:

0x2f9d532cb164783c880668275e9c63a7b665037af06fa833fc6d730f57e43b0e

The message i currently have on DDEX is "Please wait while we verify your transaction(s) on the blockchain. This may take a few minutes"

Comment: I don't know how DDEX works (you mentioned MyEtherWallet) but your second transaction hasen't been sent to the network. Otherwise you would see it.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. I will query this with ddex.